# Assigning list as prototype acts differently than assigning a simpler object

Tags: javascript, prototype, assign

Can someone please help explain why I'm unable to assign this list as an object prototype in the same manner that I can assign a simpler object property? My understanding was that obj_a & obj_b should each get their their own _amount & _list instances.

This returns unique values for each object... as expected:

```
const Amount = {
  _amount: 0,
  set_Amount: function (foo) {
    this._amount = foo;
  },
  get_Amount: function () {
    return this._amount;
  },
};

function func_a() {}
function func_b() {}

const obj_a = new func_a()
const obj_b = new func_b()

Object.assign(func_a.prototype, Amount);
Object.assign(func_b.prototype, Amount);

obj_a.set_Amount(1)
obj_b.set_Amount(2)

console.log(obj_a.get_Amount()) //1
console.log(obj_b.get_Amount()) //2
```

But the arrays are being consolidated here... so they seem to share the same instance??

```
const objList = {
  _list: [],
  add_item: function (foo) {
    this._list.push(foo)
  },
  list: function () {
    return this._list;
  },
  total: function (){ 
    let x = 0;
    for (let item in this._list) {
      x = Number(x) + Number(this._list[item]);
    }
    return x;
    }
}

function type_a() {}
function type_b() {}

const obj_a = new type_a()
const obj_b = new type_b()

Object.assign(type_a.prototype, objList);
Object.assign(type_b.prototype, objList);

obj_a.add_item(1)
obj_a.add_item(2)
obj_b.add_item(3)
obj_b.add_item(4)

console.log(obj_a.list()) //  [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(obj_a.total()) // 10
console.log(obj_b.list()) //  [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(obj_b.total()) // 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the array is an object, so even when you merge a clone of `objList` with `Object.assign()`, the nested objects are shallow copied, or copied by reference. This is unlike [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) such as numbers, strings, booleans, etc, which are copied by value.

```js
// Create
const baseObj = {
  list: [], // Object
  num: 0 // Primitive
}

// Clone
const testA = {...baseObj}
const testB = {...baseObj} 

// Mutate
testA.num = 5;
testB.list.push(2);

// Test
console.log('Are Objects copied by reference? ', testA.list === testB.list)
console.log('Are Primitives copied by reference? ', testA.num === testB.num)
```

We need to deep clone `objList` to create completely new instances of everything inside. We can use lodash's `cloneDeep()` to do this:

```js
const objList = {
  _list: [],
  add_item: function (foo) {
    this._list.push(foo)
  },
  list: function () {
    return this._list;
  },
  total: function (){ 
    let x = 0;
    for (let item in this._list) {
      x = Number(x) + Number(this._list[item]);
    }
    return x;
    }
}

function type_a() {}
function type_b() {}

Object.assign(type_a.prototype, _.cloneDeep(objList));
Object.assign(type_b.prototype, _.cloneDeep(objList));

const obj_a = new type_a()
const obj_b = new type_b()

obj_a.add_item(1)
obj_a.add_item(2)
obj_b.add_item(3)
obj_b.add_item(4)

console.log(obj_a.list())  
console.log(obj_a.total())
console.log(obj_b.list()) 
console.log(obj_b.total())
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Extremely helpful. I haven't come across shallow vs deep cloning yet, so this was extremely helpful! Thanks for point me in the right direction.

Comment: Anytime :) Yeah, I kinda wish JS had a built in way to deep clone without needing libraries or writing our own loops/recursive functions, but it is what it is. Also if you look into it and see `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`. This does work, but it doesn't copy over functions. So it wouldn't work for prototypes.